# what does vb.net mean by "expression expected"

Tags: vb.net, expression, listitem

i dont know what to put after the bracket of the list item class, so their is an error saying

> expression expected

This is the code:

```
Dim NewEntry As New ListItem(CostOfGame & " " & Ps3Games & " " & GameID & " " & IsTheGameInStock & " " &)
```

Also, can you please explain to me what list item does in simple terms as i still dont understand it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an extra '&' at the end of your expression.  It should just be:

```
Dim NewEntry As New ListItem(CostOfGame & " " & Ps3Games & " " & GameID & " " & IsTheGameInStock & " ")
```

As to what a ListItem is and what it does, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx). I suspect, though that an answer that you want is a little broader and beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra ampersand in there (the last one):

```
... IsTheGameInStock & " " &)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you are using syntax in an incomplete fashion.  For math, you are forgetting to use an equal sign "=" on the line throwing the exception.  You are forgetting to say for example

```
Dim x As Single

x = Math.Sqrt(16)
```

but you are doing something like

```
Math.Sqrt(16)
```

or you do are something like

```
InStr(string,"hello")>0
```

instead of

```
If InStr(string,"hello")>0 Then
   .....
End IF
```